# getting:Error: ngModel:nonassign Non-Assignable Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

I have created a filter to calculate sum of the input values inside ng-repeat and am accessing that filter outside the ng-repeat am getting the  error as **:Error: ngModel:nonassign Non-Assignable Expression** how do I resolve it, below is my code

```
**HTML**
     <input type="disable" ng-disabled="true" class="form-control"  name="count" ng-model="table.fields | mysum">

**Angularjs Filter**

      app.filter('mysum', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var sum = 0;
    items.forEach(function(item) {
     if (item.item_count) {
         sum += item.item_count;      
      }     
    })
    return sum;
  }
})
```

Comment: if you put ng-model="table.fields", it works fine? Take a look a this example of filter. http://plnkr.co/edit/vtNjEgmpItqxX5fdwtPi?p=preview

Comment: @IgnacioChiazzo you understood my quesion

Answer (score 3):

ng-model is a two way binding. What you are trying to do is bind it to a filter output. Which is not supported.

Instead use this `value="{{table.fields | mysum}}"`

Comment: then how I can access the value using node js using req.body

Comment: If all you need to do is display the value, you don't need to use `ng-model` simply using the template bindings `{{value}}` is fine. Did you replace ng-model with value?

Comment: <input type="disable" ng-disabled="true" class="form-control" value="{{table.fields | mysum}}" name="count"> I have done like this and its not working

Comment: You should be using type="text". Are you getting a different error?